# How to save the text in textfield in swift?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4

I have a tableview consisting of 2 cells and each cell has a textfield. I'd like to hold the text in textfield in an another variable and append it into an array but it just save the second cell's textfield's text into the variable and doesn't append the array.

Here is cellForRowAt code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if tableView == queryTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: queryCellReuseIdentifier,
                                                   for: indexPath) as! queryCell

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.gray

            queryTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
            queryTextField.delegate = self
            queryTextField.placeholder = "Soruyu buraya giriniz"
            queryTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
            cell.addSubview(queryTextField)

            return cell

        }
```

Here is my related function :

```
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        var temp = queryTextField.text!
        queryArray.append(temp)

        print(temp)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if your project is non-storyboard approach, then I would say, it would be more easier and flexible to take control of each type and data and action since sometimes things not quite flexible with storyboard only.. . as you create, even a single UIElement, UI conforms to those properties, methods and actions which you define, means fully customized code  - custom defined code base..

now to your question, according to what you did, probably, your textfield text is overwritten to blank, losing the previously entered value every time the cell is  dequeued, cell is generated fresh again for use every time " dequeue cell " method is executed, if you want to persist your previous value, I would say,  " remind the dequeued cell that it had some value before being re- dequeued again " means:

1. declare your global array or dict.
2. dequeue your cell and setup your cell properties
   3 after cell is dequeued, do something like this, and your cells previous value is saved even after the cell is dequeued.

example, common approach:

```
struct DefaultInfo {
     var string: String?
     var type: SomeData? //optional
}

 let array: [DefaultInfo] = []
  
 var array = self.array[indexPath.row]

 // after cell is dequeued:
 switch array.type {
        case .someCase:
          
          let string = cell.textField.text
          array.string = string
          cell.textField.text = array.string
          //print(array.string!)
          // now you should be able to see your input after cell is 
          //renewed.. . try it.. .
        
       default: break
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an independant variable `queryTextField` which is overriden when you create the second cell.

Also, in `textFieldDidEndEditing` try accessing `textField` instead of `queryTextField`, like this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     var temp = textField.text!
     queryArray.append(temp)

     print(temp)
}
```

Responding to this:

> I need every cell has its textfield and I need to be able to save
>   their texts into an array. After that I am going to send them to web
>   service. To sum up, they will be my parameters.

1. You don't need to have global `queryTextField` just for that. You can remove this variable, if that's its only goal.
2. Do you need to send web request on some trigger? Like button tap. I assume, yes.
3. Since theoretically not all your cells are visible at the same time (e.g. when thay do not fit the screen), it's bad idea to try and track texts in text fields. Instead, you need some kind of model to store all texts (paired with indeces, maybe). The simplest would be dictionary where key is cell identifier (e.g. `indexPath`) and value is the text.
4. In `textFieldDidEndEditing` you can report the changes to the view controller. For this you need to assign the cell as the delegate for its text field. And view controller - as the delegate for the cell. In  `textFieldDidEndEditing` cell would be calling view controller delegate method to report the text change, passing (for example) self and text as parameters. View controller would then be able to find its index path and store the text in the model (dictionary).
5. On trigger (button click?) view controller will be able to build parameters from the model (dictionary).

Consider this pseudocode as a direction:

```
cellForRow {
  ...
  cell = ...
  let textField = ...
  textField.delegate = cell
  cell.addSubview(textField)
  cell.delegate = self
}
```

In cell:

```
textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  delegate?.report(text: textField.text ?? "", in: self)
}
```

In view controller:

```
report(text: String, in cell: UITableViewCell) {
  let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(of: cell)
  model[indexPath] = text
}
```

Comment: I have defined queryTextField as global :  `var queryTextField = UITextField() ` @Evgeniy

Comment: And you are overwriting it each time in `cellForRowAt`. So what's the point of having it?

Comment: Now, I feel my mistake but still couldn't figure out that how to make it right. Because this is really big project and there thousands lines of codes. What is the most effective way? @Evgeniy

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. I gave you example code in my answer. Is that not what you are looking for? If not, what then? Maybe I didn't understand your problem correctly?

Comment: I am new to create an interface without using storyboard. I need every cell has its textfield and I need to be able to save their texts into an array. After that I am going to send them to web service. To sum up, they will be my parameters. @Evgeniy

Comment: Updated the answer